# Angular 2 ngFor for nested json

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am new angular 2. I am able to get Json file. I am able to get some part json file but not the array inside json file.
For example I want to visualise GPS device in First UL and IMU device in second UL. SInce they are array I am getting same data of IMU device in bOTH the lists.

json file

```
"config" : [
    {
        "id"      : "gps_device",
        "name"    : "GPS Device",
        "type"    : "String",
        "widget"  : "dropdown",
        "fields"  : [ "Disabled", "XSensIMU", "GenesysADMA"],
        "default" : "Disabled"
    },
    {
        "id"      : "imu_device",
        "name"    : "IMU Device",
        "type"    : "String",
        "widget"  : "dropdown",
        "fields"  : [ "Disabled1", "XSensIMU1", "GenesysADMA1"],
        "default" : "XSensIMU"
    }
]
```

```html
//here I should get loop of GPS device array
<h1>Gps Device</h1>
<ul *ngFor="let drop of config[0]">
  <li *ngFor="let sub of drop.fields"> {{sub}}</li>
<ul>
//here array of IMU device

<h1>IMU Device</h1>
<ul *ngFOr="let drop1 of config[1]">
    <li *ngFOr="let sub1 of drop.fields"> {{sub1}}</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to show two lists . the data is from json file. For  first list data is config[0].fields and for second list data is config[1].fields

Comment: `let sub1 of drop1.fields"`

Comment: @echonax that is typing mistake from my side. actually that doesnt solve problem

Comment: @RajeshChoudary look at your code, you are trying to iterate `config[0]` wich is an object inside `ngFor`. It won't work. You need something like `config[0].fields`. Check: http://plnkr.co/edit/ikMLxCzdCjhivaVwb2Wj?p=preview

Comment: DV for lack of research, this is a clear dup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to separate your devices into 2 groups :

```
<div *ngFor="let drop of config">
  <ng-container *ngIf="drop.id === 'imu_device'; else gpsBlock">
    <h1>IMU Device</h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFOr="let sub1 of drop.fields"> {{sub1}}</li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container #gpsBlock>
    <h1>Gps Device</h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFOr="let sub1 of drop.fields"> {{sub1}}</li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

You loop on config, and conditionnally display device in GPS or IMU divs

**EDIT :**
Or you can doing it this way :

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let drop of configs">
    <h1>{{drop.name}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let field of drop.fields">{{field}}</li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: problem with this approach is, it is going second loop every time

Comment: Check out the second way so, it may be your solution